# Can't hear sound from my speakers - any ideas?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have a Dell Inspiron N5110 that won't play sound. To be more specific, I can't hear any sound from the speakers when running Ubuntu 16.04. I also dual boot Windows 7 on the machine and sound works fine there.

Here is an exhaustive list of screenshots, command output, and troubleshooting information:

#### Hardware

```
$ lspci
...
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
...
```

#### pavucontrol

[image]

#### alsamixer

[image]

#### pactl info

```
Server String: /run/user/1000/pulse/native
Library Protocol Version: 30
Server Protocol Version: 30
Is Local: yes
Client Index: 7
Tile Size: 65472
User Name: nathan
Host Name: nathan-laptop
Server Name: pulseaudio
Server Version: 8.0
Default Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
Default Channel Map: front-left,front-right
Default Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
Default Source: alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
Cookie: 1da0:01c2
```

#### ps aux | grep pulse

```
nathan    5952  1.5  0.1 416424 10576 ?        S<l  16:01   0:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
```

#### dmesg | grep snd

```
[    8.215325] snd_hda_codec_idt hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for 92HD87B1/3: line_outs=1 (0xd/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[    8.215330] snd_hda_codec_idt hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    8.215333] snd_hda_codec_idt hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0xb/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    8.215335] snd_hda_codec_idt hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    8.215337] snd_hda_codec_idt hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[    8.215340] snd_hda_codec_idt hdaudioC0D0:      Internal Mic=0x11
[    8.215342] snd_hda_codec_idt hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0xa
```

Let me know if more information is needed and I can easily add it to the question.

#### Further Updates

- ALSA doesn't seem to be working at all — `aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Right.wav` was completely silent

Comment: One thing missing (don't know if it helps any though) is: `cat /proc/asound/card0/codec* | grep Codec` on my system it yields:  **Codec:** IDT 92HD91BXX
**Codec**: Intel PantherPoint HDMI

Comment: Before looking at Pulse Audis: does ALSA work at all? Try `aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Right.wav`.

Comment: @Takkat doesn't seem to work; updated the question.

Comment: Are you able to hear sound through your headphones? If you can't, it might be an audio driver issue. Have you tried going to settings>software & updates>additional drivers and then looking for something not enabled? Maybe you have an nvidia GPU that's using the wrong driver.

Comment: Does it works with headphones¿? If yes try to plug in a headset, then try to switch output _(with headphones plugged in)_ to speakers. Check if it works then. I had the same issue with (may be) the same Dell model and started working after a small _output-switching game_ with headphones plugged in.

Answer (score 1):

I had problems with my audio recently on an HP laptop. 
After reading a few articles, I installed pulseaudio and kmix, updated everything, rebooted and then everything was fine. 
I am pretty new to this so this may be a long way round but it worked for me.

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio 
sudo apt-get install kmix
sudo apt-get update
```

Reboot and everything worked for me. 
Hopefully this may have helped.

Answer (score 0):

You could install the packages rhythmbox and amarok. They have the necessary drivers for sound-output.

> sudo apt-get install rhythmbox amarok
>
> sudo reboot

Comment: Any proof that they have necessary driver for sound-output? It's typically not media players job to provide driver

Comment: @Anwar - I know from a similiar thread, which I answered same way in earlier Ubuntu distro, that this was successful.

Answer (score 0):

Since the release of Ubuntu 16.04 there have been many updates to the pulse audio and its related programs. I recommend you to update anything related to audio at first. Ubuntu 17.04 is very good at handling audio devices compared to 16.04 which was terrible and 16.10 which was better, so you could try Ubuntu 17.04 on a live CD and install if you find it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
   amixer sset 'Master' 50%
```

Try setting the volume with these.

```
   amixer -q sset Master toggle
```

For mute and unmute.